# How to submit to the server with JQuery.UI Dialog and ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a way to submit information captured in a JQuery Dialog to the server in ASP.Net. I originally thought it would work with a 'hidden' asp button, but the click doesn't seem to be submitting the form. Here's the code I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var dlg = jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 150,
            width: 300, 
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
            "Add": function() {
                    var btn = document.getElementById("<%=btnAdd.ClientID %>");
                    if (btn) btn.click();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $("#dialog").parent().appendTo("#dialog_target");

  });
</script>
```

```
<div id="hidden" style="visibility:hidden" >

    <!-- Hidden button that actually triggers server add -->
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" 
            runat="server"
            style="display:none"
            OnClick="btnAdd_Click"  />

<!-- Hidden Delete Dialog -->
<div id="dialog" title="New Additional Skill">
        <label>Additional Skill Name:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="_txtNewSkillName" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

Your hidden button approach is good, but your elements may still not be inside the `<form>` when you submit though.

To resolve this, just place the dialog inside the `<form>`, to make sure it submits...otherwise the button that you're clicking isn't in `POST` set to the server, and the event won't fire.

You would do this by adjusting your `.appendTo()` call, like this:

```
$("#dialog").parent().appendTo("form");
```

Since you're only dealing with 1 `<form>`, this is all you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a form to the dialog then submit the form using JavaScript when you close the dialog or click the button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but in FireFox form elements decorated with display:none will not be included in the POST data to the server. So I think your form *is* submitting, but ASP.NET won't execute your serverside btnAdd_Click function, because it cannot find the button in the POST data.

Try changing display:none to

```
visibility:hidden;
```

or

```
position:absolute;
top:-999px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getpostbackeventreference.aspx) rather than setting up a call to `btn.click()`:

```
buttons: {
    "Add": function() {
        <%= ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(
                new PostBackOptions(this.btnAdd))%>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoops - fixed a typo. I copied this straight from my test file and had my Button's variable name instead of yours. D:

Answer (score 0):

try this:

__doPostBack('btnAdd','OnClick');

This would simulate a button click event and it would postback to the server. In the page load event use this to set the reference:

Page.GetPostBackEventReference(btnAdd)

Hope this helps.